# Красивый UI для автоматического вывода таблиц

Tags: php, yii2

Есть какая-нибудь интересная библиотека для формирования из вывода var_dump таблицы, вкладок и т.д.? То есть не json, не вывод с отступами, а именно читабельная таблица для обычного человека (необычным человекам привет). Можно, конечно, писать под каждый вывод свое формирование таблицы или UI, но хотелось бы готовое решение, так как выводы могут быть разные.

Фреймворк Yii2 если что, мало ли что конкретно для него готовое есть)

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html

Comment: @u_mulder и где там что-то кроме вывода форматированного текста? В вопросе просьба посоветовать что-то для формирования полноценного UI или таблиц/вкладок.

Comment: перепишите задание, я тоже подумал в сторону @u_mulder